# SpeakerBox via CallKit on Xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: swift, xcode8, callkit

[SpeakerBox](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) application made by Apple doesn't work anymore after update to Xcode 8 beta 6.
It logs an error:

> Error requesting transaction: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=2 "(null)"

Where Code=2 is a [CXErrorCodeRequestTransactionErrorUnknownCallProvider](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit/cxerrorcoderequesttransactionerror/cxerrorcoderequesttransactionerrorunknowncallprovider?language=objc) error.

Everything worked fine on Xcode 8 beta 4.

Does anybody know what is happened there?

Comment: The error appears because a signature of a function application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions was changed and the application doesn't call it.

Answer (score 2):

I had to correctly fix function signatures in app delegate class.
They were changed in iOS 10.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it!

Comment: What call was it? My CXProvider is resetting all the time and I run into the same error eventually, perhaps it's related.

Answer (score -1):

Download the latest version of the SpeakerBox source code - it changed with each version of the beta iOS 10 SDK that was released.  (Note that the SDK has not changed with the latest 2 betas of iOS 10 - as witnessed by the fact that the Xcode beta is still at beta 6, although the OS itself is at beta 8).

Comment: Please, give me a link for an updated version of a SpeakerBox app.

Comment: The link hasn't changed, it's still at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html

The sample code is dated 3rd August, which was last updated between Beta 4 (1st Aug), and Beta 5 (9th Aug)

Comment: Thanks, but these sources are incompatible with Xcode 8 beta 6, I had to fix them to make them compatible with a new Swift dialect.